# A question about the DE $\ddot{x} + x = \frac{-3A^3}{4}\sin(t + \phi) + \frac{A^3}{4} \sin(3(t + \phi))$, where $A$ and $\phi$ are constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I am trying to solve the DE

$$\ddot{x} + x = \frac{-3A^3}{4}\sin(t + \phi) + \frac{A^3}{4} \sin(3(t + \phi)) $$

And here is my attempt and my question is at the bottom:

First we have the homogenous solution for $\ddot{x} + x =0$ which looks like

$$x_h = c_1 \cos(t) + c_2 \sin(t), c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$$

Then I find one particular solution to the original DE:

Suppose $x_{p1}$ looks like

$$x_{p1} = B \sin(3t + 3\phi) + Ct \cos(t+ \phi)$$

Then we have

$$\ddot{x}_{p1} = -9B \sin(3t + 3\phi) - 2C\sin(t+ \phi) - Ct\cos(t+ \phi)$$

And this implies

$$\ddot{x}_{p1} + x_{p1} = -8B \sin(3t + 3\phi) - 2C\sin(t+ \phi)$$

So we have

$$\frac{-3A^3}{4}\sin(t + \phi) + \frac{A^3}{4} \sin(3(t + \phi)) = -8B \sin(3t + 3\phi) - 2C\sin(t+ \phi)$$

which means

$$\begin{cases}
  \dfrac{-3A^3}{4} = -2C\\
  \\
  \dfrac{A^3}{4} = -8B
  \end{cases}$$

$$\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
              B = \dfrac{A^3}{-32}\\
              \\
              C = \dfrac{3A^3}{8}
              \end{cases}$$

So this particular solution is

$$x_{p1} = \dfrac{A^3}{-32} \sin(3t + 3\phi) + \dfrac{3A^3}{8}t \cos(t+ \phi)$$

$\textbf{Question:}$ How to find another particular solution? I tried other combinations of $\sin, \cos$ and $t$, but I failed. If someone is willing to offer some help, that will be very nice! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want another particular solution? The *general* solution to the differential equation is $x_h+x_{p1}$.

Comment: @Gonçalo I remember that we need two particular solutions and one homogeneous solution for this kind of DE and the general solution looks like $x= x_h + x_{p1} + x_{p2}$

Comment: In this case, don't trust your memory. Please consult any book on differential equations.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for your help! I consulted my instructor, and he agreed with your idea.